# Transparent and untouchable activity/service?

Tags: android, service, touch, overlay

I am trying to create a new transparent activity/service to detect long presses on the screen at all times that does not interfere with the usual touches that user makes except the long presses. so far i have been able to do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    //this.getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    View myview = GestureOverlayView.inflate(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.traslucent, null);
    setContentView(myview);
    myview.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

This is just for test not actual long press.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

I was able to detect the touch behind the activity(as i wanted) and toast didnt show up.But The screen is black except for a cloud i put there. I need to make it transparent, how to do this?

Comment: You mean even when the user is not using your app?

Comment: I mean user sees a transparent screen, and gets to work with the screen the way it is, except that i get to know when a long press happened. I even thought of starting a service but couldn't write a code for that. I would rather prefer to use a service

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a transparent activity theme in your styles.xml file. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then, in your AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:theme="Theme.Transparent"
  ... />
```

Comment: no man sorry but its still black out there. didnt turn transparent. but also this time the cloud image i had was not in its actual position, it was in the center. although i tried Simply this in my manifest:
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
and the original position was restored